# AWS Lambda permission denied when trying to use ffmpeg

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I want to write a handler that responds to S3 put events to convert any avi files that are uploaded to mp4. I doing it in Java, in Eclipse, with the AWS toolkit plugin. For video conversion, I am using ffmpeg with [ffmpeg-cli-wrapper](https://github.com/bramp/ffmpeg-cli-wrapper), and I have provided a static (linux) binary of ffmpeg in the source tree.

I have found that when I upload the function, the binary gets put in `/var/task`, but when I try to use the test function I've written, I get a "permission denied" error.

```
import net.bramp.ffmpeg.FFmpeg;

public class LambdaFunctionHandler implements RequestHandler<S3Event, String> {

    private static final String FFMPEG = "/var/task/ffmpeg";

    public String handleRequest(S3Event event, Context context) {

        try {
            FFmpeg ff = new FFmpeg(FFMPEG);
            System.out.println(ff.version());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return "foo";
    }
}
```

And the first line of the stacktrace: `java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/var/task/ffmpeg": error=13, Permission denied`.

How do I execute this binary? I have done as others have suggested and `chmod 755` the binary before uploading, but it hasn't made a difference.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

AWS Lambda runs on Amazon Linux. It is a known issue. Try building (with static enabled) and check if it works on Amazon Linux and upload that binary. You do not have the privileges to `chmod` the files in `/var/task/`. Or try this solution that works:

- Move `ffmpeg` to `/tmp`
- `chmod 755 /tmp/ffmpeg`
- Call `/tmp/ffmpeg`

See this [discussion](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=583910) for more info.

Comment: How do I move the file? Is it something I can do once from the command line or do I need to do this in the code at the start of the method?

Comment: At the start of the method. If `mv` fails, try `cp`. It always worked for me.

Comment: Sorry for not getting back to you earlier. I used `ProcessBuilder` to do as you said and it all works nicely. Thanks for the help!

Comment: you can also use Files.copy in Java

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue recently, and after messing with various manual solutions, what really solved the issue was:

1. Create a Lambda Layer, with only the `ffmpeg` binary inside a `bin/` folder
2. Create a Lambda Function to implement said layer, and in the python code run `/opt/bin/ffmpeg`

See https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/media/processing-user-generated-content-using-aws-lambda-and-ffmpeg/

Answer (score 0):

As helloV mentioned, you might have to include a static ffmpeg binary and copy it to a location and execute from there.
A detailed answer, (node.js code) is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29001078/358013)