# AWS Lambda. Error=20 (Not a directory) when moving FFmpeg to /tmp

Tags: ffmpeg, aws-lambda, tmp

I am using the [ffmpeg-cli-wrapper](https://github.com/bramp/ffmpeg-cli-wrapper) to run FFmpeg from an application I upload onto AWS lambda. I was initially getting the

> error=13 Permission Denied

when trying to call it via the wrappers `ProcessBuilder`. My inital solution was to `chmod 755` ffmpeg before uploading, but it didn't help.

For information, my FFmpeg and ffprobe files are located in the following classpath: `static/ffmpeg/ffmpeg` and `static/ffmpeg/ffprobe`. They are also statically linked.

[AWS Lambda permission denied when trying to use ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36063411/aws-lambda-permission-denied-when-trying-to-use-ffmpeg)

I've tried to follow the instructions given in the example above, but when I try to perform either mv or cp command:`Runtime.exec("mv " + pathToFFmpeg + " /tmp")`, I get the

> error=20, Not a directory

error.

I know that I have the correct path for FFmpeg because the following command `mv *pathToFFmpeg* *an arbitrary name*` runs without error, meaning that the file is there and so the mv command just renames it as it's supposed to do.

Comment: The error doesn't seem to make sense, but your home directory is not writable, so moving shouldn't work.  Try `cp`.

Comment: Well, I fixed this issue by switching over to `ProcessBuilder` (was using `Runtime.exec()` before). Now I'm getting `error=13, Permission denied` again when accessing ffmpeg in /tmp (even after `chmod 755` 'ing the files in /tmp), should i ask a new question for this?

Comment: I've fixed that issue as well now! I was initially `chmod 755`ing the files from windows 10 bash, but I found out that it had no afffect all along. I found a way to do the same thing in windows and now I can use FFmpeg. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Excellent.  For the benefit of others experiencing the same issue, please write an answer describing exactly how you fixed it.

Comment: fosho, thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

I was creating the JAR from a windows environment, and my understanding is that chmod 755'ing in the lambda environment had no effect because of this.

**Solution**: Before JARing in Windows, give permissions to the 'Everyone' group to the files, or to any directories that may contain. It didn't show up for me so I had to add the permission group. This seems to solve both the error=20 and error=13 errors that I was getting. [Screenshot of menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebQdy.png). Note that I STILL had to include `chmod 755` on lambda function or else I would get error=13 again.

I also ran into an error=2 (No such file or directory), which I've so far been able to resolve by: 
a) Switching from `Runtime.exec()` to `ProcessBuilder`. 

             (I suppose Runtime.exec() is less 'refined' and needs extra configuration) 
b) Using `cp` rather than `mv`. 
c) Running the `ProcessBuilder` from the same method I call FFmpeg from, rather than calling different methods of the same class to accomplish this. No clue why this is...