# Compile ffmpeg as stand alone binary

Tags: ffmpeg, compilation

I'm trying to compile `ffmpeg` as a standalone binary (because I want to use it in AWS lambda)

I can get things to work fine on the server where I'm compiling, but if I copy the binary and run it from another server, I get:

`./ffmpeg: error while loading shared libraries: libvdpau.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

So it sounds like something didn't made it into the binary. From what I've read, I've to compile ffmpeg with the flags `--disable-shared` and `--enable-static`, which I've done:

```
PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH" PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib/pkgconfig" ./configure \
  --prefix="$HOME/ffmpeg_build" \
  --pkg-config-flags="--static" \
  --extra-cflags="-I$HOME/ffmpeg_build/include" \
  --extra-ldflags="-L$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib" \
  --bindir="$HOME/bin" \
  --disable-shared \
  --enable-static \
  --enable-gpl \
  --enable-libass \
  --enable-libfreetype \
  --enable-libmp3lame \
  --enable-libvpx \
  --enable-libx264
PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH" make
make install
make distclean
hash -r
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--enable-static` and `--disable-shared` only affect `libav*` binaries. It doesn't prevent linker to use necessary shared object files.

For a pure static lib, this is going to be tricky and mess. You have to build every static lib you need, then try to add additional ldflags to configure.

Another alternative is some tools packing those libs/elfs/binaries into a big one. Some of them are listed here: [Pack shared libraries into the elf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386579/pack-shared-libraries-into-the-elf)

Comment: Ok I'll try that. Thanks a lot! I'm trying to use that with AWS lambda and I need to upload a binary with everything if I want to use external programs...

Answer (score 4):

Even though I didn't succeed to compile everything in one binary, I've been able to upload the dependencies to AWS lambda by doing:

#### copy all dependencies in a folder

I wrote a python script to do that. The script relies on `lld` to list the dependencies.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess
import os
from shutil import copyfile

def copyLibraries(bin, destination):
  if not os.path.exists(destination):
    os.makedirs(destination)

  output = subprocess.Popen(["ldd", bin], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
  for l in output.split('\n'):
    if len(l.split("=> ")) > 1:
      lib_location = l.split("=> ")[1].split(" ")[0].strip()
      if lib_location != "":
        real_location = os.path.realpath(lib_location)

        lib_name = real_location.split('/')[-1]

        copyfile(real_location, destination + lib_name)

        if os.path.islink(lib_location):
          link_name = lib_location.split('/')[-1]
          if link_name != lib_name:
            os.symlink(real_location, destination + link_name)

copyLibraries("/home/ubuntu/bin/ffmpeg", "/home/ubuntu/libs/")
```

#### AWS lambda

- include the ffmpeg binary as well as the libs folder in the lambda zipped code.
- in the lambda code, include the corresponding paths. In `node.js` this can be done as:

.

```
process.env['PATH'] = process.env['PATH'] +
  ':' +    process.env['LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT'] +
  ':' + process.env['LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT'] + '/bin' +
  ':' + process.env['LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT'] + '/lib';
```

Comment: i an set process.env['PATH'] same as above given but got error Error: spawn EACCES and i am using aws lamda function and text on aws cli

Answer (score 3):

Add     `--extra-ldexeflags="-static"`  to get a standalone ffmpeg.

Answer (score 0):

If you have [Nix](https://nixos.org) on your developer machine, you can do this with one command:

```bash
nix-build '<nixpkgs>' -A pkgsStatic.ffmpeg-full
# this might take a while, since you're compiling **everything** required by ffmpeg
# once this is done, check that the file is what you need
file ./result/bin/ffmpeg
```

If you are on an ARM64 Linux and need a static **AMD**64, it's different. Check [Denis Gosnell's blog](https://functor.tokyo/blog/2021-10-20-nix-cross-static) for more details.