# Can't run binary from within python aws lambda function

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, pyinstaller

I am trying to run this tool within a lambda function: https://github.com/nicolas-f/7DTD-leaflet

The tool depends on Pillow which depends on imaging libraries not available in the AWS lambda container. To try and get round this I've ran pyinstaller to create a binary that I can hopefully execute. This file is named `map_reader` and sits at the top level of the lambda zip package.

Below is the code I am using to try and run the tool:

```
command = 'chmod 755 map_reader'
args = shlex.split(command)
print subprocess.Popen(args)

command = './map_reader -g "{}" -t "{}"'.format('/tmp/mapFiles', '/tmp/tiles')
args = shlex.split(command)
print subprocess.Popen(args)
```

And here is the error, which occurs on the second `subprocess.Popen` call:

```
<subprocess.Popen object at 0x7f08fa100d10>
[Errno 13] Permission denied: OSError
```

How can I run this correctly?

Comment: I'd guess the environment you're running in doesn't allow you to set local files to be executable. "Permission denied" may mean exactly what it says.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may have been misled into what the issue actually is.

I don't think that the first Popen ran successfully. I think that it just dumped a message in standard error and you're not seeing it. It's probably saying that

```
chmod: map_reader: No such file or directory
```

I suggest you can try either of these 2:

1. Extract the map_reader from the package into /tmp. Then reference it with `/tmp/map_reader`.
2. Do it as recommended by Tim Wagner, General Manager of AWS Lambda who said the following in the article [Running Arbitrary Executables in AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/running-executables-in-aws-lambda/):

> Including your own executables is easy; just package them in the ZIP file you upload, and then reference them (including the relative path within the ZIP file you created) when you call them from Node.js or from other processes that you’ve previously started. Ensure that you **include the following at the start of your function code**:

```
process.env[‘PATH’] = process.env[‘PATH’] + ‘:’ + process.env[‘LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT’]
```

The above code is for Node JS but for Python, it's like the following

`import os
os.environ['PATH']`

That should make the command `command = './map_reader <arguments>` work.

If they still don't work, you may also consider running `chmod 755 map_reader` **before** creating the package and uploading it (as suggested [in this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29001078)).

Comment: Marking as correct although it wasn't a full solution for me. I'll post another answer with the other issue. The critical thing here was moving the binary to /tmp so I could act upon it.

Comment: I forgot to mention making sure you compiled for Amazon Linux. I assumed you took care of that. I'm glad you figured it out.

Comment: didn't the adding LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT to your path not work for you?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I was still getting Permission Denied error from that.

Answer (score 6):

I know I'm a bit late for this but if you want a more generic way of doing this (for instance if you have a lot of binaries and might not use them all), this how I do it, *provided you put all your binaries in a bin folder next to your py file, and all the libraries in a lib folder* :

```
import shutil
import time
import os
import subprocess

LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT = os.environ.get('LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT', os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
CURR_BIN_DIR = os.path.join(LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT, 'bin')
LIB_DIR = os.path.join(LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT, 'lib')
### In order to get permissions right, we have to copy them to /tmp
BIN_DIR = '/tmp/bin'

# This is necessary as we don't have permissions in /var/tasks/bin where the lambda function is running
def _init_bin(executable_name):
    start = time.clock()
    if not os.path.exists(BIN_DIR):
        print("Creating bin folder")
        os.makedirs(BIN_DIR)
    print("Copying binaries for "+executable_name+" in /tmp/bin")
    currfile = os.path.join(CURR_BIN_DIR, executable_name)
    newfile  = os.path.join(BIN_DIR, executable_name)
    shutil.copy2(currfile, newfile)
    print("Giving new binaries permissions for lambda")
    os.chmod(newfile, 0775)
    elapsed = (time.clock() - start)
    print(executable_name+" ready in "+str(elapsed)+'s.')

# then if you're going to call a binary in a cmd, for instance pdftotext :

_init_bin('pdftotext')
cmdline = [os.path.join(BIN_DIR, 'pdftotext'), '-nopgbrk', '/tmp/test.pdf']
subprocess.check_call(cmdline, shell=False, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

Answer (score 2):

There were two issues here. First, as per Jeshan's answer, I had to move the binary to /tmp before I could properly access it.

The other issue was that I'd ran pyinstaller on ubuntu, creating a single file. I saw elsewhere some comments about being sure to compile on the same architecture as the lambda container runs. Therefore I ran pyinstaller on ec2 based on the Amazon Linux AMI. The output was multiple .os files, which when moved to tmp, worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

```
copyfile('/var/task/yourbinary', '/tmp/yourbinary')
os.chmod('/tmp/yourbinary', 0555)
```

Moving the binary to `/tmp` and making it executable worked for me

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to copy the files the `/tmp`. You can just use [ld-linux](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ld-linux.so) to execute any file including those not marked executable.

So, for running a non-executable on AWS Lambda, you use the following command:

```sh
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /opt/map_reader
```

P.S. It would make more sense to add the `map_reader` binary or any other static files in a Lambda Layer, thus the `/opt` folder.

Answer (score 1):

[Like the docs mention for Node.js](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/running-executables-in-aws-lambda/), you need to update the `$PATH`, else you'll get `command not found` when trying to run the executables you added at the root of your Lambda package. In Node.js, that's:

```js
process.env['PATH'] = process.env['PATH'] + ':' + process.env['LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT']
```

Now, the same thing **in Python**:

```py
import os

# Make the path stored in $LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT available to $PATH, so that we
# can run the executables we added at the root of our package.
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + os.environ['LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT']
```

Tested OK with Python 3.8.

(As a bonus, here are some more [env variables used by Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-envvars.html).)