# Update permissions on AWS Lambda file to make it executable

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

## Overview:

I have some C++ code (`myProgram`) that I want to execute from a Lambda function. I have built the code on an Amazon Linux EC2 instance, and it runs there without problem.
When I try to run it from a Python script in Lambda, I receive the following error message:

> Command 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/var/task/lib; /var/task/myProgram -d' returned non-zero exit status 126.: CalledProcessError

I see from the [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Exit-Status.html) that 126 means the command is found but is not executable. It is executable before I upload it to Lambda, so I'm not sure how to resolve this.

***Edit***: Thanks to the comment below, I double checked the permissions on the Lambda instance. Indeed, the file is not marked as executable after it has been uploaded. When I try changing it with `chmod`, I get an error `Read-only file system`.

## Details:

When I package this and upload it to my lambda function, the directory structure looks like this:

- handler.py
- myProgram
- lib

  - (required libraries)

Here is the code for `handler.py`

```
import os
import subprocess

exepath = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'myProgram')
libdir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'lib')

def handler(event, context):
    command = 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH={}; {} -d'.format(libdir, exepath)
    return subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

If I change `shell=True` to `shell=False` then I receive a different error

> [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/var/task/lib; /var/task/myProgram -d': FileNotFoundError

## Question:

How can I make `myProgram` executable? I don't see any mention of this process in the [Lambda blog on executables](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/running-executables-in-aws-lambda/)

Comment: The `777` permissins (`rwxrwxrwx`), is that something you confirmed "locally" or on the Lambda server?  If not on Lambda, can you convince Lambda to dump the permissions of `myProgram`?  Can you dump the user and group of the executable and the process that is trying to execute it?  (Theories: (a) "upload to Lambda" messed with permissions, and it isn't executable.  (b) there is some security against running globally writable executables on the Lambda system, or executing outside group/user)

Comment: You are right. I checked the permissions locally and assumed they would be preserved, but they aren't. On the lambda instance they are `rw-rw-r--`. Now... how to change that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the solution to this thanks to the tip from Yakk and the answer to [Can't run binary from within python aws lambda function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41651134/cant-run-binary-from-within-python-aws-lambda-function).

I had to copy `myProgram` to `/tmp` and then `chmod` to be able to execute the it.

```
command = 'cp ./myProgram /tmp/myProgram; chmod 755 /tmp/myProgram; LD_LIBRARY_PATH={}; /tmp/myProgram -d '.format(libdir)
return subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```